# Using Firebase Auth with an external database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I'm currently using Firebase to authenticate my users in a React/Node app, but I also want to store additional user data in my own database and I'm doing so by storing the Firebase `uid` on each user and I wanted to get some input on my implementation to make sure I'm on the right track.

My frontend code is as follows:

1. This is used as an `onClick` on a "Continue with Google" button:

```
const googleSignIn = async () =>
    signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
```

2. When the above popup promise completes, `auth.onAuthStateChanged` is triggered in the following `useEffect`, which (on login/signup) would trigger the function `applicationAuthentication`, passing in the user object returned from Firebase:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      if (!firebaseUser) {
        return dispatch(logUserOut());
      }
      return applicationAuthentication(firebaseUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

3. The `applicationAuthentication` looks as follows:

```
const applicationAuthentication = async (firebaseUser: User) => {
    try {

      const idToken = await firebaseUser.getIdToken();

      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/users/authenticate/signin', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`
        }
      });
      const { user, error } = data;

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }

      dispatch(logUserIn({ user, accessToken: idToken }));

    } catch (error: any) {
      dispatch(setUserError(error.message));
      console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

In my node express server, the following happens at the route `/api/users/authenticate/signin`; this is where I communicate with my own database by using the data access methods `findUserByFirebaseUID` and `createUser` using the `uid` from the token to check if the user exists, and if not, creating a new one (note the middleware that's checked first as noted below):

```
usersRouter.get(
  '/authenticate/signin',
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const uid = res.locals.uid; // set by token middlewear function

      let firstLogin = false;
      let user = await findUserByFirebaseId(uid);

      if (!user) {
        firstLogin = true;
        user = await createUser(uid);
      }

      res.json({ user, firstLogin });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Which uses the following `authenticate` middleware function to authenticate the user with `firebase-admin`:

```
const authenticate = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);

    if (decodedToken) {
      const { uid } = decodedToken;
      res.locals.uid = uid;
      return next();
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Unauthorized Request' });
  } catch (error) {
    next({ message: 'Invalid Token' });
  }
};

app.use(authenticate);
```

Does this overall flow of using the `uid` to check my own database seem correct? And am I implementing the token middleware correctly?

I'd love to hear any thoughts on this!

Comment: Do you want to store additional data for the same user? Like PII info? Firebase Auth has custom fields where you can add more data, like another object, and you can retrieve that data. But if you want to save something different, like user-related data such as a complete Item personalization, you can just save the uid, ( like you are doing ) and it seems to be ok.

Comment: The data that I'm interested is basically custom user data such as username, roles, youtubeChannelURL, etc. Are these examples of what you're referring to as "complete item personalization"?

Comment: No, Complete personalization I usually refer to and entire profile page, but that's ok, you can add those fields too into firebase auth custom fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way you pass the ID token from the client to the server, and then decode it (in the middleware) on your server to securely determine the UID is similar to how Firebase's own services do this.

If you pass the ID token to other requests to to authorize them, consider keeping a cache of recent raw and decoded ID tokens, to prevent having to decode them on each request.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'll definitely consider caching the tokens.